# Convert istream to ifstream?

Tags: c++

I am following a tutorial from http://programmingnotes.freeweq.com/?p=3144 for the assigned project. Problem is that the project spec asks that the spellchecker will be called through `main` by this function:
 `void spellCh(istream& inf, istream& wordlistfile, ostream& outf)`
whereas the tutorial uses `iftream` and `ofstream`. So when I try this

```
void spellCh(istream& inf, ostream& outf)
{    
    ifstream& inf1 = inf;
    ofstream outf1= outf;        
}
```

It gives me an error on both lines : **Non-const lvalue reference to type 'ifstream' (aka 'basic_ifstream') cannot bind to a value of unrelated type 'istream' (aka 'basic_istream')**

Please help because I have spent a day trying to figure it out. What kind of code would accomplish it?

Comment: If you just want to read/write to the streams with `<< >>` operators, you can do that on `inf` and `outf` directly. You don't need to convert them to file streams inside the function.

Comment: Wow that is some ugly looking C++ in the tutorial. Looks like it was written by a C programmer. But I don't see `spellCh(istream& inf, istream& wordlistfile, ostream& outf)` on the page you link too.

Answer (score 1):

`std::istream` and `std::ostream` are direct base classes of `std::ifstream` and `std::ofstream` respectively. Due to something called [*polymorphism*](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)), a derived class is also considered its base class and can be implicitly covered to a pointer or reference thereto (upwards conversion). Because of this, one can simply pass these instances to the parameters of the functions and it will successfully be converted by the compiler to their base class' type.

> Non-const lvalue reference to type `'ifstream'` cannot bind to a value of unrelated type `'istream'`

For base-to-derived conversion (downwards conversion), there are no implicit conversions. You would have to cast using `static_cast` with the target type as `std::ifstream&`.

Comment: Not dynamic_cast for safety?

Comment: @NeilKirk Why? Since we know `std::istream` is guaranteed to be a base class of `std::ifstream`, we don't need that kind of cast. Sure one should do it with user-defined classes and when they're not entirely certain, but in this situation we have 100% certainty.

Comment: Do we know that from the information in the question? OP is a beginner and cost of dynamic_cast is so low in context of writing to a stream. Better safe than sorry. It's like disabling bounds checking because we're "sure" we're in bounds.

Comment: @Nik-Lz It's only undefined behavior if the dynamic (target) type isn't an actual derived class.